# Doubt about the explicit toroidal and poloidal components of a confined plasma in Tokamaks

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields, plasma-physics, fusion

### Introduction

Since the magnetic field is solenoidal: $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$, it is possible to decompose it as:

> $\vec{B} = \vec{B}_{T} + \vec{B}_{P} \tag{1}$

where $\vec{B}_{T}$ is the *Toroidal magnetic field* and $\vec{B}_{P}$ is the *Poloidal magnetic field*. This vector decomposition is called *Toroidal-Poloidal decomposition* $[1]$.

Now, in toroidal fusion reactors, or Tokamaks, the intuitive picture of the magnetic field lines of $\vec{B}$, $\vec{B}_{T}$ and $\vec{B}_{P}$ is given by Figure $1$:

> [image]
>
> Figure $1$: The magnetic fields of a Tokamak system.

### My question

#### An illustrative example:

Well, if you want to plot the magnetic field lines of a **magnetic dipole**, you simply take the field $[2]$:

> $\vec{B}_{\mathrm{dip}} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi r^{3}}2cos\theta \hat{r} + \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi r^{3}}sin\theta \hat{\theta} \tag{2}$

and perform a coordinate transformation $(r,\theta,\phi) \to (x,y,z)$ to get $[2]$, $[3]$:

> $\vec{B}_{\mathrm{dip}} = \frac{3 \mu  m x z}{4 \pi 
>    \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}}\hat{x}+\frac{3 \mu  m y z}{4 \pi 
>    \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}}\hat{y}-\frac{\mu  m
>    \left(x^2+y^2-2 z^2\right)}{4 \pi 
>    \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}} \hat{z} \tag{3}$

with $(3)$ you can use your favorite software to plot the magnetic configuration. Using mathematica you should get (Figure $2$):

> [image]
>
> Figure $2$: The magnetic field lines of theoretical magnetic dipole.

#### The question:

So, my question is simple: I want to plot the magnetic field lines of $\vec{B}$, $\vec{B}_{T}$ and $\vec{B}_{P}$. For this I need to know the components of  $\vec{B}_{T}$ and $\vec{B}_{P}$, then perform a coordinate transformation and plot the lines. But I simply didn't find them in any book on plasma physics! Therefore: **what are the components and, in general, the explicity form of the toroidal magnetic field $\vec{B}_{T}$ and poloidal magnetic field $\vec{B}_{P}$ for the tokamak geometry?**

$$--------------------$$

$[1]$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poloidal%E2%80%93toroidal_decomposition

$[2]$ GRIFFITHS.D. *Introduction to Electrodynamics*. page 255.

$[3]$ https://pages.vassar.edu/magnes/mathematica/

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field of a tokamak is far more complicated than that of a magnetic dipole. Assuming an axisymmetric ideal MHD equilibrium leads to the [Grad-Shafranov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grad%E2%80%93Shafranov_equation). This can be solved numerically for a specified toroidal current density, $\mathbf{j}_{\phi}$. Assuming the current density is linearly related to the [poloidal flux](http://fusionwiki.ciemat.es/wiki/Flux_surface) yields the Solov’ev solution. For large aspect ratio, [Wesson's Tokamaks](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Tokamaks.html?id=iPlAwZI6HIYC&redir_esc=y) provides the approximate large aspect ratio solution:

$B_{\phi} = \frac{B_{\phi 0} R_0}{R}$

$B_{\theta} = B_{\theta a} \frac{1 - \left (1 - \frac{r^2}{a^2} \right )^{\nu+1}}{r / a}$

where its assumed current $j \propto \left (1 - \frac{r^2}{a^2} \right )^{\nu}$ and pressure $p \propto 1 - \frac{r^2}{a^2} $. Here the [simple toroidal coordinates](http://fusionwiki.ciemat.es/wiki/Toroidal_coordinates) are used, which you can readily transform to cylindrical and then Cartesian coordinates for plotting.

Comment: Thank you! So, what are the $B_{\phi 0}$, $B_{\theta a}$ and $R_{0}$ explicitly? And the $R$ is given in the fusionwiki for toroidal coordinates?

Comment: Apologies, $B_{\phi 0}$ is the toroidal magnetic field at $R = R_0$ (center of the cross section) and $B_{\theta a}$ is the poloidal magnetic field at $r = a$ (edge of plasma). $R$ and $R_0$ are respectively distance from axis of symmetry and torus major radius (as per the link).